# Setting KeyCodes Equal to OVRInput Buttons?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, oculusquest

I'm relatively new to C# and I was wondering if there was any way I could do something simple that would make my keycode (spacebar, it activates the lightsaber I have) equal to the grip trigger (the Axis1D.PrimaryIndexTrigger). What I was trying to do was have it so if I pressed the spacebar the lightsaber would turn on, and if I pressed the same button again it would turn off. Basically I don't want to have to rewrite in terms of OVRInput because it is already set the way it is, but I'm not sure how to do this. Thanks in advance! :)

Also: this isn't all my code in case that wasn't obvious... just included the important stuff

```
/// <summary>
    /// The key for toggling the weapon's active state
    /// </summary>
    private KeyCode TOGGLE_KEY_CODE = KeyCode.Space;
        
        // key pressed
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(TOGGLE_KEY_CODE))
        {

            ToggleWeaponOnOff();

        }
```

Edit: This is what I tried, which did not work

```
/// <summary>
    /// The key for toggling the weapon's active state
    /// </summary>
    private KeyCode OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.One);
        
        // key pressed
        if (OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.One))
        {

            ToggleWeaponOnOff();

        }
```

Comment: And what is wrong with your current code? It seem to be correct implied that it is in an Update method.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, I get no errors, I just really am not sure how to set a KeyCode (spacebar) equal to a button on the Oculus Touch Controller, or if that is even possible. Just looking for a bit of help, I'll edit the post with what I tried already.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice should lie in the lands of Unity's new Input System, which is much, MUCH better, robust and flexible than the old one.
The general concept behind the solution is the following:

- you creating the Input Action maps in a form of scriptable objects,
- each Action can contain multiple input sources, like Spacebar key and Index trigger together,
- new Input System is collecting all inputs according to the active mappings and then invoking the Actions if the tresholds are met (like dead zones or modifier keys),
- and as a result, you'll have to only handle the InnputAction or InputActionReference objects in a preferable way: either using it in old-style:

  if (ActionFire.isTriggered)
  {
  //Do stuff
  }
  ...or by subscribing on the Action's events, but in this case you should use the UserInputManager object (or write your own) which is effectively doing all the stuff you was previously done within Update().